# Open same activity with different result. From MainActivity

Tags: java, android, listview, listactivity

I am wondering if it is possible to open a new activity but with different results depending on which button has been pressed. For example:

Main Activity - 
btnApple
btnBanana
btnGrape
btnOrange
...

Pressing any of these buttons would take you to "FruitInfoActivity" however, depending on the button pressed would give you a different text view of say a description of the fruit.

The alternative is to have a new activity for every single fruit, which as an example would be a lot of activities.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass information in the intent you create for starting the new activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FruitInfoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("FRUIT_NAME", "Apple");
startActivity(intent)
```

And you can get this information in new Activity (FruitInfoActivity) to show it in your text field.

Answer (score 1):

> The alternative is to have a new activity for every single fruit, which as an example would be a lot of activities.

This is not an alternative. If you make separate activities for each 'fruit' that would be very bad design.

Comment: I agree which is why I looked for another method. Thanks for your input.